Unreal 5 IOS build error/Remote build as I change image icons
Trying to build on my windows comp did the certificate and profile work on the mac so now I am able to build and Installed it too on an ios device, Now the only problem I have is when I change the icons in unreal it doesnt let me build simple throw an unknown error/ ask me to do a remote build which ig is building on a mac comp, As i dont have the mac currently, Is a mac really required just for an icon?? I've given them the correct sizes and stuff what could be the issue?
tried replacing the original images with my icons by doing that it built but as I installed it still shows me the default unreal icon
